# Position taxonomy header image field in template

Tags: theming, entities, 8, media

I have a list of taxonomy terms to structure my content.

- Apples
- Oranges
- Bananas

In admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/catalog/overview/fields I added the field_header_image (an Header image field). Now I am able to upload a term-specific Header image.

So if I go the url /apples/ my Apples Header image shows up.

How can I position field_header_image in my template?

Comment: Are you using a template file? if not you could use manage display.

Comment: When you say `position` do you mean before/after some other field?

Comment: @NoSssweat the Header image field must always be in the my header-image-section... At a fixed position just below the nav-bar.

Comment: sounds like all you have to do is use CSS. Ex:  `.header-image { position: fixed; top: 20px; }`